# Site on OpenGL call performance

Tags: performance, opengl

I'm searching for reliable data on OpenGL's functions performance. A site that could for example:

1. ...answer me how much more efficient is using glInterleavedArrays compared to gl*Pointer based implementation with strides, or without them. If applicable, show the comparisions on nVidia vs. ATI cards vs. embedded systems.
2. ...answer me how much of a boost is gained in using VBO's vs. non-buffered data in the cases of static, dynamic and stream data.

I'd like to find a site that has "no-bullshit" performance data, not just vague statements like "glInterleavedArrays are usually faster than direct gl*Pointer usage".

Is there such a dream-site? Or at least somewhere where I can get answers to the forementioned questions?

*(yes, I know that nothing will beat hand-profiling, but the fact that something works faster on my machine, doesn't mean it's faster generally on all cards...)*

Comment: What's the deal with this weird performance tag? O.o

Comment: that's "advertisement". a company paid to get their logo on perf. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more about application level benchmarking than measuring performance of individual features, but it might be possible to learn something from [specviewperf](http://spec.unipv.it/gwpg/gpc.static/vp10info.html), especially if it's possible to discover more about what OpenGL mode each benchmark uses to perform it's rendering.  The benchmark seems to include some [options](http://spec.unipv.it/gwpg/gpc.static/whatis_vp8.html) to tweak usage of display lists, vertex arrays etc, but I don't think SPECs published [results](http://spec.unipv.it/gwpg/gpc.static/vp10results.html) go into any analysis of the effects of changing these from the defaults.  They don't seem to have any [VBO](http://spec.unipv.it/gwpg/gpc.static/vbo_whitepaper.html) coverage yet.

Comment: +1 : thank you for the links, but it's not what I'm searching for. The lack of such site is annoying to the point that I'm thinking of creating my own -_-

Comment: I'd be interested to see such a site.  Note that microbenchmarks testing just one thing can be misleading; e.g I've benchmarked blits and line drawing separately on AMD and Nvidia and got similar results... then found enormous differences when you test interleaved blitting and line drawing.  The good thing about specviewperf is it keeps the vendors focused on real world application performance (I believe it was started as an antidote to vendors competing on escalating claims of however many triangles-per-second; these numbers told you little about how the card would actually perform).